# Closed form defines locally a function?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, differential-geometry, differential-topology, differential-forms

In my particular example, I have a volume form on a one-dimensional manifold, so i.e. this volume form $dx$ is closed. Now, I was wondering, does the integral function $f(y):=\int_{x_0}^{y} dx$ define $f$ locally as a function?

Since I got the impression in the comments that my question is somewhat unclear. Why does it hold for a general closed form on a manifold $M$ that the integral defines $f(y):=\int_{x_0}^{y} dx$ locally $f$ as a function?

Comment: Yes. And (locally) that function's derivative is your form.

Comment: is there a theorem that tells me this or how can I show this?- In particuar, how does the closedness of the form enter?

Comment: On a one-dimensional manifold, this is nothing more than the fundamental theorem of calculus. Closedness is irrelevant, because every $1$-form on a $1$-manifold is closed.

Comment: @JackLee yes, but I would like to understand how this works in the general setting, if we have only closed forms, too. Cause then, I think, the statement is still true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\omega$ is a closed $1$-form on a smooth manifold $M$, then in any contractible open set $U$, you can define a function $f$ such that $df=\omega$. This is a special case of a the *Poincaré lemma*, which says that every closed form is locally exact.

To define $f$, choose a point $x_0\in U$ and let $f(x) = \int_{\gamma_x}\omega$, where for each $x\in U$, $\gamma_x$ is some specific path from $x_0$ to $x$. Because closedness of $\omega$ and contractibility of $U$ guarantee that the integral is path-independent, this is sometimes written as $\int_{x_0}^x\omega$.

For more details, see Chapter 11 of my [*Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1441999817) (2nd ed.).